# Recyclerview с несколькими viewholders

Tags: android, recyclerview

Помогите настроить адаптер, который бы выводил 3 разных типа вьюхолдеров просто списком.

код:

адаптер:

```
public class TestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

    private Context context;
    private List<Model> listItems;

    TestAdapter(Context context, List<Model> listItems){
        this.context = context;
        this.listItems = listItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        switch (listItems.get(position).type) {
            case 0:
                return Model.YOUR_MESSAGE_TYPE;
            case 1:
                return Model.INTERLOCUTOR_MESSAGE_TYPE;
            case 2:
                return Model.ADVERTISING_INTEGRATION_TYPE;
            default:
                return -1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view;
        switch (i) {
            case Model.YOUR_MESSAGE_TYPE:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.your_message_item, viewGroup, false);
                return new YourMessageVH(view);
            case Model.INTERLOCUTOR_MESSAGE_TYPE:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.interlocutor_message_item, viewGroup, false);
                return new InterlocutorMessageVH(view);
            case Model.ADVERTISING_INTEGRATION_TYPE:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.advertising_integration_item, viewGroup, false);
                return new AdvertisingIntegrationVH(view);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        Model object = listItems.get(i);
        switch (object.type) {
            case Model.YOUR_MESSAGE_TYPE:
                Picasso.get().load(object.getImage()).into(((YourMessageVH) viewHolder).image);
                ((YourMessageVH) viewHolder).message.setText(object.getMessage());
                ((YourMessageVH) viewHolder).date.setText(object.getDate());
                ((YourMessageVH) viewHolder).message.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "CALLBACK TO Activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                break;
            case Model.INTERLOCUTOR_MESSAGE_TYPE:
                Picasso.get().load(object.getImage()).into(((InterlocutorMessageVH) viewHolder).image);
                ((InterlocutorMessageVH) viewHolder).message.setText(object.getMessage());
                ((InterlocutorMessageVH) viewHolder).date.setText(object.getDate());
                break;
        }
    }


    private class YourMessageVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView image;
        TextView message;
        TextView date;

        private YourMessageVH(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_your_image);
            message = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_your_message);
            date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_your_message_date);
        }
    }

    private class InterlocutorMessageVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView image;
        TextView message;
        TextView date;

        private InterlocutorMessageVH(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_interlocutor_image);
            message = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_interlocutor_message);
            date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_interlocutor_message_date);
        }
    }

    private class AdvertisingIntegrationVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        Button button;

        private AdvertisingIntegrationVH(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.b_show_reward);
        }
    }
}
```

дата:

```
public class Data {

    public static ArrayList<Model> getModelList() {
        ArrayList<Model> list = new ArrayList<>();

        String date = "18.04.2019";
        String johnSnowImage = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/901947348699545601/hqRMHITj_400x400.jpg";
        String ygritteImage = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/c/c4/Ygritte-Rose_Leslie.jpg/220px-Ygritte-Rose_Leslie.jpg";

        Model yourFirstMessage = new Model();
        yourFirstMessage.setType(Model.YOUR_MESSAGE_TYPE);
        yourFirstMessage.setImage(johnSnowImage);
        yourFirstMessage.setMessage("Игритт, подожди!");
        yourFirstMessage.setDate(date);
        list.add(yourFirstMessage);

        Model interlocutorFirstMessage = new Model();
        interlocutorFirstMessage.setType(Model.INTERLOCUTOR_MESSAGE_TYPE);
        interlocutorFirstMessage.setImage(ygritteImage);
        interlocutorFirstMessage.setMessage("Ничего ты не знаешь, Джон Сноу!");
        interlocutorFirstMessage.setDate(date);
        list.add(interlocutorFirstMessage);

        Model yourSecondMessage = new Model();
        yourFirstMessage.setType(Model.YOUR_MESSAGE_TYPE);
        yourFirstMessage.setImage(johnSnowImage);
        yourFirstMessage.setMessage("Кое-что я знаю. Знаю что люблю тебя. Знаю что ты меня любишь. Но сейчас мне нужно домой!");
        yourFirstMessage.setDate(date);
        list.add(yourSecondMessage);

        Model firstAdvertisingIntegration = new Model();
        firstAdvertisingIntegration.setType(Model.ADVERTISING_INTEGRATION_TYPE);
        list.add(firstAdvertisingIntegration);

        return list;
    }

}
```

Пример:

Recyclerview должен показывать "yourFirstMessage", "interlocutorFirstMessage" , "yourSecondMessage" и потом "firstAdvertisingIntegration" (все они находятся в классе Data)

Но оно показывает как "yourSecondMessage", "interlocutorFirstMessage" потом пустой блок cardview и в конце "firstAdvertisingIntegration".

Просто втупую нужно подряд чтобы выводило из списка. Спасибо.

Comment: В `onCreateViewHolder`: `switch (getItemViewType(i))`. А в `onBindViewHolder` добавить кейс для третьего типа

Comment: @woesss не помогло(

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример того как можно создать адаптер с разными ViewHolder.

Для начала стоит создать базовый ViewHolder

```
public abstract class BaseViewHolder<T extends BaseData> extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    BaseViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }

    public abstract void bind(T data, IOnItemClickListener listener);
}
```

После чего создать нужные вам ViewHolder унаследованные от базового

```
public class PictureViewHolder extends BaseViewHolder<PictureItem> {

    private TextView mText;
    private ImageView mImageView;

    public PictureViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.picture_text_view);
        mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_image_view);
    }

    @Override
    public void bind(PictureItem data, IOnItemClickListener listener) {
        mText.setText(data.getData().getText());
        Glide
                .with(mImageView.getContext())
                .load(data.getData().getUrl())
                .into(mImageView);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> listener.onItemClick(((PictureItem) data).getData().getText() + " clicked"));
    }
}


public class SelectorViewHolder extends BaseViewHolder<SelectorItem> {

    private ListView mSelector;

    public SelectorViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mSelector = itemView.findViewById(R.id.selector_list_view);
    }

    @Override
    public void bind(SelectorItem data, IOnItemClickListener listener) {
        List<String> variants = new ArrayList<>();
        for (VariantsItem variantsItem : data.getData().getVariants()) {
            variants.add(variantsItem.getText());
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(itemView.getContext(),
                R.layout.selector_element, variants);
        mSelector.setAdapter(adapter);
        mSelector.setOnItemClickListener((parent, view, position, id)
                -> listener.onItemClick(variants.get(position) + " clicked"));
    }
}


public class TextViewHolder extends BaseViewHolder<TextItem> {

    private TextView mText;

    public TextViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_text_view);
    }

    @Override
    public void bind(TextItem data, IOnItemClickListener listener) {
        mText.setText(data.getData().getText());

        itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> listener.onItemClick(((TextItem) data).getData().getText() + " clicked"));
    }
}
```

Далее в адаптере

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseViewHolder> {

    private static final int TEXT_OBJECT = 0;
    private static final int PICTURE_OBJECT = 1;
    private static final int SELECTOR_OBJECT = 2;

    private IOnItemClickListener mClickListener;
    private List<BaseData> mDataList = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyAdapter(@Nullable IOnItemClickListener listener) {
        mClickListener = listener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public BaseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return getByType(parent, viewType);
    }

    private BaseViewHolder getByType(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        BaseViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        switch (viewType) {
            case TEXT_OBJECT:
                viewHolder = new TextViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_text, parent, false));
                break;
            case PICTURE_OBJECT:
                viewHolder = new PictureViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_picture, parent, false));
                break;
            case SELECTOR_OBJECT:
                viewHolder = new SelectorViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_selector, parent, false));
                break;
        }

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BaseViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.bind(mDataList.get(position), mClickListener);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Log.e("xxx","getType: " + mDataList.get(position).toString());
        if (mDataList.get(position) instanceof TextItem) {
            return TEXT_OBJECT;
        }
        if (mDataList.get(position) instanceof PictureItem) {
            return PICTURE_OBJECT;
        }
        if (mDataList.get(position) instanceof SelectorItem) {
            return SELECTOR_OBJECT;
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public void replaceItems(List<BaseData> models) {
        mDataList.clear();
        mDataList.addAll(models);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Этой мой пример, если вдруг будет непонятно, позже могу попробовать адаптировать под ваш код.

https://medium.com/@sreekumar_av/recyclerview-with-multiple-type-t-of-views-and-how-to-bind-without-casting-5f453e4436aa
Здесь можно почитать доп инфу

Comment: Похожую реализацию когда-то использовал когда нужно было нативную рекламу прикрутить в список.